# Convert list in entity to single string column in database

Tags: string, hibernate, arraylist

I have a `VARCHAR` field in my database, and the value of this field is `val1,val2,val3`.

Is it possible to set this into an `ArrayList<String>` attribute of an entity using comma as split delimiter?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you use JPA 2.1, then you can create an `AttributeConverter`:

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
    // Java 8
    return String.join(",", list); 
    // Guava
    return Joiner.on(',').join(list); 
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
  }

}
```

You can use this converter in your entity:

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
private List<String> strings;
```

For before JPA 2.1 you could do this by hand:

```
@Entity
private MyEntity {
  ...
  private String strings;

  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return Arrays.asList(strings.split(","));
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> list) {
    strings = String.join(",", list);
  }
}
```

I wrap `Arrays.asList` in an `ArrayList` in the converter, because the result is stored in the attribute and any change to that list will be written back to the database - thus I need a changeable list (I can't add anything to the result of `Arrays.asList`). In the *before 2.1* solution the result is not connected with the attribute and a changeable list would not be synchronized with the attribute.

To query for an entity that contains a specific item in such an attribute, see my answer [here](/questions/50355913/jpql-query-for-item-in-list-stored-with-attributeconverter/50583780#50583780)

Comment: but how do you jpql query that for example this list contains a certain value?

Comment: As I mentioned in my last sentence, that question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355913/jpql-query-for-item-in-list-stored-with-attributeconverter/50583780#50583780

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is possible.

With Hibernate 4.3.x+ you can define an `AttributeConverter` although I am pretty sure this will not work for early Hibernate versions because of the `List` type. See this for an example: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

The other way to make this work is by implementing a custom `UserType` and annotating the field/getter with `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`. Here is a nice write up of this with examples: http://blog.xebia.com/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/

Yet another way which is JPA compatible is to have two fields, the `List` annotated with `javax.persistence.Transient` and the `String` but then you have manage the state synchronization between these two field in `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate` listeners yourself. Here an example for using listeners: http://alexandregama.org/2014/03/23/entity-listeners-and-callback-methods-jpa/

Answer (score 3):

Try to use @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable annotations

Comment: you save my day

Comment: That is not what the question asks for, though.

Comment: Indeed. This creates another table. Not true

Comment: Please do not use this. Create your own table instead before using that and a specific entity and manage it with awareness!

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a comma in your `String`, `split()`/`join()` won't be enough. For those searching a better/different solution, here it is - made by serialize to JSON and deserialize from JSON. The downside is more characters used in the database, but it works for the most of text you can have.

```
package ...;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class StringArrayConverter
        implements AttributeConverter<String[], String>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2744576922911393664L;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final String[] attribute) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute);
        }
        catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final JsonProcessingException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, String[].class);
        }
        catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final JsonProcessingException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The example of usage:

```
package ...;

import ....StringArrayConverter;

import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonWithCars {

    @Id @NotNull @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;

    @Convert(converter = StringArrayConverter.class)
    private String[] cars = new String[0];

}
```

Comment: problem with converter is the possibility to use JPA repositories...