# Java hibernate how can I persist List of entities without relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, entity

How can I persist a list of entities in one column of a table?

I'm trying to store result after a user has answered a random set of multiple choice questions with one answer being correct.
The two tables being "quetions" and "result". So I want to store all the questions that was picked to a column in "result" preferable without relationship/mapping.

When I try this it creates multiple tables like this:

"questions"

"result_questions" This one containing result_id and question_id like it would
be a manyToMany relationship..

"result"

```
@Entity
public class Questions{
private String question;
private String[] options;
private String answer;
}

@Entity
public class Result{

private int score;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;


@ElementCollection
private List<MultipleChoice> questions;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Tobias Liefke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4371659/tobias-liefke) answer to this question: [Convert list in entity to single string column in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048978/convert-list-in-entity-to-single-string-column-in-database). This way you will have a text column with questions splitted by the characters you defined on the converter.