# JPQL query for item in list stored with AttributeConverter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.1

As Tobias Liefke suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048978/convert-list-in-entity-to-single-string-column-in-database/50352664?noredirect=1#comment87724535_50352664), I have implemented an `AttributeConverter` to store list values into a single string column separated by commas.

Converter Class:

```
public class ListNumbersConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Long>, String>
```

Field in Entity class:

```
@Column(name = "user_ids", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = ListNumbersConverter.class)
private List<Long> userIds;
```

It is working fine but I can't query the records for specific list items. I tried using `IN` operator in JPQL query like below:

```
? in userIds
```

With this I get only a result if input param is the first element in the DB value. e.g: DB value is "1,2,3". I am able to retrieve this record if input param value is 1 for above mentioned query, but not able to retrieve if value is either 2 or 3. How do I have to write my query to retrieve all records that contain a specific item?

My database is MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't know *how* the converter maps the list to the column. It can't build a mapping from the JPQL `? in userIds` to the matching SQL fragment, as it would need to know how your converter is implemented.

But you can always build that SQL fragment yourself, for example:

```
WHERE concat(',', entity.userIds, ',') LIKE concat('%,', ?, ',%')
```

The first `concat` is to ensure that the expression matches even the first and last value of the list (which wouldn't start or end with the separator).

There are other DB specific functions that could be used, but this example works on all database types I know of.

*Another remark:* You should not try to join `userIds` in the query - as it is of a *basic* type, even if it is a list. See the JavaDoc of `@Convert`:

> The Convert annotation is used to specify the conversion of a Basic field or
>   property.

Nevertheless Hibernate will complain if you compare your attribute directly with a literal (`entity.userIds = '1'`) because the type of the attribute doesn't match the type of the literal. But as long as you use a function like above for either side of the comparison it won't complain.

Comment: thanks for explanation and suggested solution worked.