# I have a problem with "You may also like" feature in Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a simple "You may also like" feature for a blog.
There are posts and each of them has one or more tags. Also a tag can contain many posts. I want to implement the feature where you open a post and the posts, which have similar tags, are recommended to you.

So i created 3 entities:

Post.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @Column
    private String author;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    Set<PostTags> postTags;

    public Post(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Set<PostTags> getPostTags() {
        return postTags;
    }

    public void setPostTags(Set<PostTags> postTags) {
        this.postTags = postTags;
    }
}
```

Tags.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Tags {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
    Set<PostTags> postTags;

    public Set<PostTags> getPostTags() {
        return postTags;
    }

    public void setPostTags(Set<PostTags> postTags) {
        this.postTags = postTags;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

PostTags.java

```
@Entity
public class PostTags {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    private Tags tag;

    public PostTags(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public Tags getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(Tags tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

And repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface PostTagsRepository extends JpaRepository<PostTags, Long> {
    @Query("select p.post from PostTags p where p.tag.id IN :tagIds")
    Set<Post> findPostsbyTagIds (List<Long> tagIds);
}


@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Post p where p.author = :author")
    Set<Post> findPostsByAuthor(String author);
}
```

I managed to create this feature in an amateurish way, but better than nothing. I piled up everything in one method just to test it:

```
 @GetMapping("/posts")
    public Set<Post> showRecommendedPosts(){

        //Imitate post id
        long postId = 1;
        Post postFound = postRepository.findById(postId).get();
        Set<PostTags> postTags = postFound.getPostTags();

        List<Long> listTagIds = new ArrayList<>();

        //extract ids of the tags from the post
        for(PostTags tag : postTags){
            listTagIds.add(tag.getTag().getId());
        }

        //find posts by Author
        Set<Post> postsByAuthor = postRepository.findPostsByAuthor(postFound.getAuthor());

        //find posts by Tags
        Set<Post> postsByTagIds = postTagsRepository.findPostsbyTagIds(listTagIds);

        //We combine both sets
        Set<Post> recommendedPosts = new HashSet<>(postsByAuthor);
        recommendedPosts.addAll(postsByTagIds);
        recommendedPosts.remove(postFound);

        return recommendedPosts;
    }
```

But this works only if i manually add data to "post_tags" table in the db like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my question, i don't know how to add multiple tags to a post in Spring. Because it would be something like this:

```
 PostTags newPostTag1 = new PostTags();
        newPostTag.setPost(post1);
        newPostTag.setTag(tag1);

        PostTags newPostTag2 = new PostTags();
        newPostTag2.setPost(post1);
        newPostTag2.setTag(tag2);

        PostTags newPostTag3 = new PostTags();
        newPostTag3.setPost(post1);
        newPostTag3.setTag(tag3);
```

And so on...
Therefore, it's not an option. So how can i save tags correctly? Or have my entities been created incorrectly? What is my mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the idea behind `Tag` being an Entity.

How I see it is you use the `postTags` and change it to `tags`. This `tags` would be a Set of an enum if you want to restrict the user or a Set of String other way. After that, I would add an endpoint that return post based on a tag or a list of tags for your `You may also like` feature. This endpoint just make a request to the database (find posts where tags contains givenTag max 10). At the end, you only have one entity :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @Column
    private String author;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    Set<String> tags;

    // ...
}
```

Converter implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048978/convert-list-in-entity-to-single-string-column-in-database)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But could you give me a hint one more time? To select post by tags i had to use a native query because i failed to write a jpql one correctly. So this query works:     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE `tags` LIKE %:tag% OR `author` LIKE %:author%" , nativeQuery = true)
    Set<Post> findPostsByTagsAndAuthor(String tag, String author);

Comment: So how to write it in jpql because i tried this: Query("select p from Post p where :tag in(p.tags)")     and it doesn't work beacuse it requires p.tags not to be a set. I'll be happy if you help me! Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that `p.tags` is just a String and not a subquery. That's why `in` doesn't work. If you really want to use `in`, I just found out that `@ElementCollection` would work. Basically, it makes another table to store the list. That way you will be able to do a join table followed by a `in`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried this option also, it creates another table so it doesn't suit me. So i decided to stick with the native query